# When to use JOINs

Tags: sql, join

It seems to me that there are two scenarios in which to use JOINs:

1. When data would otherwise be duplicated
2. When data from one query would otherwise be used in another query

Are these scenarios right? Are there any other scenarios in which to use JOIN?

EDIT: I think I've miscommunicated. I understand *how* a JOIN works, what I'm not so sure about is **when** to use one.

Comment: If your data is spread  across more than one table, you will have no choice. And when there is a one to many relationship defined, you will have no choice but to split the data across two tables without lots of duplication. Its a pretty key concept of relational database systems (as opposed to flat files for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use joins when you need information from more than one table :)

Comment: This answer is mildly insufficient because it would apply just as well to `SELECT NAME, ID FROM CLIENT, ORDER`, which doesn't use joins.

Comment: @jemfinch then, Why self-join is introduced?

Answer (score 7):

JOINS are used to *JOIN* tables together with related information.

Tipical situations are where you have lets say

A user table where the user has specific security settings. The join would be used such that you can determine which settings the user has.

```
Users
-UserID
-UserName

UserSecurityRoles
-UserID
-SecurityRoleID

SecurityRoles
-SecurityRoleID
-SecurityRole

SELECT *
FROM Users u INNER JOIN
UserSecurityRoles usr ON u.UserID = usr.UserID INNER JOIN
SecurityRoles sr ON usr.SecurityRoleID = sr.SecurityRoleID
WHERE sr.SecurityRole = 'Admin'
```

LEFT joins will be used in the cases where you wish to retrieve all the data from the table in the left hand side, and only data from the right that match.

*JOINS are used when you start normalizing your table structure. You can crete a table with 100s on columns, where a lot of the data could possibly be NULL, or you can normalize the tables, such that you avoid having too many columns with null values, where you group the appropriate data into table structures.*

The answer to this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612296/please-explain-me-mysql-joins-in-simple-language/2612312#2612312) has a **VERY** good link that has graphical display of using JOINs

Answer (score 3):

JOINS are used to return data that is related in a relational database. Data can be related in 3 ways

- One to Many relationship (A *Person* can have many *Transactions*)
- Many to Many relationship (A *Doctor* can have many *Patients*, but a *Patient* can have more than one *Doctor*)
- One to One relationship (One *Person* can have exactly one *Passport* number)

JOINS come in various flavours:

- AN INNER JOIN will return data from both tables where the keys in each table match
- A LEFT JOIN  or RIGHT JOIN will return all the rows from one table and matching data from the other table
- A CROSS JOIN will return the product of each table