# MySQL Query, get user_ID then get Restaurant_ID then get restaurantName from 3 tables that match email at user table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm new to MySQL and I'm having problem with JOIN. Please give me some hint on how to achieve what  I need.

My Table:

```
"user" table:
- user_id
- user_name
- user_email

"favouriteRestaurant" table:
- favrst_id
- user_id
- rst_id

"restaurant" table:
- rst_id
- rst_name
- rst_city
- rst_cuisine
- rst_phone
- rst_latitude
- rst_longitude
```

My query process:

1. Get user_id "WHERE" user_email match provided email address.
2. Use the user_id to query "favouriteRestaurant", if data available.
3. Get rst_name of matching rst_id from "favouriteRestaurant" table.

The final data I need is:

1. favrst_id
2. rst_id
3. rst_name
4. rst_city
5. rst_cuisine
6. rst_phone
7. rst_latitude
8. rst_longitude

I hope my explanation is clear enough. If it's not clear please ask/comment. Thank you very much.

The following is the actual SQL (above table are simplified) I've tried so far but the result is definitely not what I wanted. It give me all restaurant instead of matching in favRst.

```
SELECT
   user.email,
   user.user_id,
   favourite_rst.restaurant_id,
   favourite_rst.restaurant_id,
   favourite_rst.user_id,
   restaurant.name
FROM
   user,
   favourite_rst,
   restaurant
WHERE 
   (user.email = 'user@abc.com')
```

Comment: So you said you are having troubles with `JOIN`, but none of your code is having the keyword `JOIN`, why don't you try to use it :)

Comment: Because I know I need to use JOIN to achieve what I need but I'm having problem in using JOIN.

Comment: What are you troubles, you should have tried using join, we could advice you where you are wrong. And the documentation is pretty clear for it - you `join` the tablename and specify `on` clause for related columns :)

Comment: Everyone get the documentation and understand everything without any issue, then why StackOverFlow exist? Try to be more productivity please instead of critics.

Comment: Well, I didn't send you to the doc's link, but instead told you you have to use `join` and `on`, maybe something which you haven't even read in the docs, so am I less productive than it? :) However, you are asking a `syntax error` question, because you cannot build syntactically you query, that's something the StackOverflow community do not like to have as questions. Even the closevote templates have it. If your questions was instead about you have joined two tables with numeric values and their SUM is not as expected, there would be more acceptable question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Please explain me MySQL Joins in simple language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612296/please-explain-me-mysql-joins-in-simple-language)

Comment: Ok fine, first, I DO read. Because I'm new, new to programming (non-programming background at all), new to MySQL, DO tried looking at others post on similar issue, I search for JOIN 3 tables. But it just can't fit what I need. So that is why I decide to make a post. Please understand, I DO NOT make a post immediately without reading documentation or search for similar case in Stackoverflow. Frankly, I'm very uncomfortable with Official Documentation because the words and example are more for graduate programmer. I always get better understanding on other tutorial site or programmer's blogs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this :

```
SELECT favrst_id, FR.rst_id, rst_name, rst_city, 
rst_cuisine, rst_phone, rst_latitude, rst_longitude
FROM user U
INNER JOIN favouriteRestaurant FR ON U.user_id = FR.user_id
INNER JOIN restaurant R ON FR.rst_id = R.rst_id
WHERE user_email = "%$email%"
```

Comment: Hi, may I know what is the meaning/purpose of "%$email%"?

Comment: `$email` is a PHP variable and it will contain the email of the user. You can use `user_email = "%$email%"` or `user_email = "$email"` for the exact match.

Answer (score 3):

You can also try this:

```
SELECT FR.favrst_id, FR.rst_id, R.rst_name, R.rst_city, 
R.rst_cuisine, R.rst_phone, R.rst_latitude, R.rst_longitude
FROM user U,
favouriteRestaurant FR,
restaurant R
WHERE U.user_email = "aaaa@example.com"
and U.user_id = FR.user_id
and FR.rst_id = R.rst_id
```

and compare the execution time using inner join and without using inner join.

Answer (score 2):

Hope it helps you

```
SELECT r.* , fr.favrst_id FROM restaurant r LEFT JOIN favourite_rst fr ON r.rst_id = fr.rst_id LEFT JOIN user u ON fr.user_id = u.user_id WHERE u.user_email = "abc@example.com"
```

Comment: @MarkZ Please always accept answers which help you as it shows that your problem is solved and then no one will invest time on it :)

Comment: @Veerendra, better to use column name for fetching the record instead of `SELECT *`. `SELECT *` exposes your system to unexpected performance and functionality changes in the case when your database schema changes.

Comment: @prava Thanks prava actually he wants all column from that table so i used SELECT * and for other table i used column name only :)

Comment: @Veerendra, I tried your solution too and it works too. Too bad I can only accept one answer. Sorry and thanks again. Voted up.