# SQLZOO #12 -- confused about multiple select & join statements

Tags: sql, join, subquery

I am attempting to answer question #12 on sqlzoo.net
(http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/More_JOIN_operations). I couldn't figure out the answer on my own but I did manage to find the answer online.

12: Which were the busiest years for 'John Travolta', show the year and the number of movies he made each year for any year in which he made more than 2 movies.

Answer:

```
SELECT yr,COUNT(title) FROM
  movie JOIN casting ON movie.id=movieid
         JOIN actor   ON actorid=actor.id
WHERE name='John Travolta'
GROUP BY yr  
HAVING COUNT(title)=(SELECT MAX(c) FROM
(SELECT yr,COUNT(title) AS c FROM
   movie JOIN casting ON movie.id=movieid
         JOIN actor   ON actorid=actor.id
 WHERE name='John Travolta'
 GROUP BY yr)  AS t)
```

One of parts that I do not fully understand is the multiple joins:

```
 FROM movie 
 JOIN casting ON movie.id=movieid
 JOIN actor   ON actorid=actor.id
```

1. Is **Actor** being joined only with **Movie**, or is actor being joined with **Movie JOIN Casting**?
2. I am trying to find a website that explains complex join statements as my attempted answer was far from correct (missing many sections). I think subselect statements with multiple complex join statements is a bit confusing at the moment. But, I could not find a good website that breaks the information up to help me form my own queries.

The other part I don't fully understand is this:

```
 (SELECT yr,COUNT(title) AS c FROM
       movie JOIN casting ON movie.id=movieid
             JOIN actor   ON actorid=actor.id
     WHERE name='John Travolta'
     GROUP BY yr)  AS t)
```

3. What is the above code trying to find?

Comment: @Karrie I searched SO for "joins explained" and found this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612296/please-explain-me-mysql-joins-in-simple-language.  Hopefully that will get you started.  Regarding subqueries, just think of them as regular queries, except that the "wrapping" query will directly act on whatever the subquery returns.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, glad you are not afraid to ask, and I'll do my best to help clarify what is going on...  Please excuse my re-formatting of the query to my mindset of writing queries.  It better shows the relationships of where things are coming from (my perspective), and may help you too.

A few other things about my rewrite.  I also like to use alias references to the tables so every column is qualified with the table (or alias) it originates from.  It prevents ambiguity, especially for someone who does not know your table structures and relationships between tables. (m = alias to movie, c = alias for casting, a = alias for actor tables).  For the sub query, and to keep alias confusion clear, I suffixed them with 2, such as m2, c2, a2.

```
SELECT
      m.yr,
      COUNT(m.title) 
   FROM
      movie m
         JOIN casting c
            ON m.id = c.movieid
            JOIN actor a
               ON c.actorid = a.id
   WHERE 
      a.name = 'John Travolta'
   GROUP BY 
      m.yr  
   HAVING 
      COUNT(m.title) = ( SELECT MAX(t.movieCount) 
                          FROM
                             ( SELECT m2.yr,
                                      COUNT(m2.title) AS movieCount
                                  FROM
                                     movie m2
                                        JOIN casting c2
                                           ON m2.id = c2.movieid
                                           JOIN actor a2
                                              ON c2.actorid = a2.id
                                  WHERE 
                                     a2.name='John Travolta'
                                  GROUP BY 
                                     m2.yr )  AS t
                     )
```

First, look at the outermost query (aliases m, c, a ) and the innermost query (aliases m2, c2, a2) are virtually identical.

The query has to run from the deepest query first... in this case the m2, c2, a2 query.  Look at it and see what IT is going to deliver.  If you ran that, you would get every year he had a movie and the number of movies... starting result from their sample data goes from 1976 all the way to 2010.  So far, nothing complex unto itself (about 20 rows).  Now, since each table may have an alias, each sub query (such as this MUST have an alias, so that is why the "as t".  So, there is no true table, it is wrapping the entire query's result set and assigning THAT the alias of "t".

So now, go one level up in the query also wrapped in parens...

```
SELECT MAX(t.movieCount)
   FROM (EntireSubquery as t)
```

Although abbreviated, this is what the engine is doing.  Looking at the subquery result given an alias of "t" and finding the maximum "movieCount" value which is the count of movies that were done in a given year.  In this case, the actual number is 3 and we are almost done.

Now, to the outermost query... again, this was virtually identical to the innermost query.  The only difference is the HAVING clause.  This is applied after all the grouping per year is performed.  Then it is comparing ITs row result set count per year to the 3 value result of the SELECT MAX( t.movieCount )...

So, all the years that had only 1 or 2 movies are excluded from the result, and only the one year that had 3 movies are included.

Now, to clarify the JOINs.  Each table should have a relationship with one or more tables (also known as linking tables, such as the cast table that has both a movie and actors/actresses.  So, think of the join as how to I put the tables in order so that each one can touch a piece to the other until I have them all chained together.  In this case

Movie -> Casting linked by the movie ID, then Casting -> actor by the actor ID, so that is how I do it visually hierarchically... I am starting FROM the Movie table, JOINing to the cast table based ON Movie ID = Cast Movie ID.  Now, from the Casting table joined to the Actor table based on the common Actor ID field

```
   FROM
      movie m
         JOIN casting c
            ON m.id = c.movieid
            JOIN actor a
               ON c.actorid = a.id
```

Now, this is a simple relationship, but you COULD have one primary table with multiple child-level tables.  You could join multiple tables based on the respective data.  Very simple sample to clarify the point.  You have a student table going to a school.  A student has a degree major, an ethnicity, an address state (assuming an online school and students can be from any state).  If you had lookup tables for degrees, ethnicity and states, you might come up with something like...

```
select
      s.firstname,
      s.lastname,
      d.DegreeDescription,
      e.ethnicityDescription,
      st.stateName
   from
      students s
         join degrees d
            on s.degreemajor = d.degreeID
         join ethnicity e
            on s.ethnicityID = e.id
         join states st
            on s.homeState = st.stateID
```

Notice the hierarchical representation that each table is directly associated under that of the student.  Not all tables need to be one deeper than the last.

So, there are many sites out there, such as the w3schools as offered by Mark, but learn to dissect small pieces at a time... what are the bare minimum tables to get from point-A to point-Z and draw the relationships.  THEN, tare down based on requirement criteria you are looking for.

Comment: Wow, thank you for taking the time to type all of that out! The student/school example was actually super useful and I did not realize you could join tables like that. Actually, once I read the student/school example, everything else in your post made sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer would be:

```
SELECT yr, COUNT(title)
FROM movie m
JOIN casting c ON m.id=c.movieid JOIN actor a ON c.actorid=a.id 
WHERE name='John Travolta' 
GROUP BY yr 
HAVING COUNT(title) > 2;
```

The answer you found (which seems to be a mistake on the sqlzoo site) is looking for any year that has a count equal to the year with the highest count.

I used table aliases in the query above to clear up how the tables are joined. Movie is joined to casting and casting is joined to actor.

The subquery that confuses you is listing each year and a count of movies for that year that star John Travolta. It's not needed if you're answering the question as written.

As for learning resources, make sure you have the basics down.  Understand everything at http://w3schools.com/sql.  Try searching for "sql joining multiple tables" in your favorite search engine when you're ready for more.

Comment: Although your query does get the correct answer, you are providing an explicit value in the HAVING clause > 2.  Yes, for movies and actor/actress to do more than 2 in a year might be extreme, but what about the underlying basis of writing queries... What if something of larger quantities, such as inventory and biggest sale item that may have 200+?  You may have many items having 200+ sales, hence the query is expecting the highest count (which coincidentally is only 3).  They need more clarification to understand what is going on.

Comment: @DRapp, I don't understand your point. The question provides an explicit value ("in which he made more than 2 movies") so an explicit value is necessary in the query. And since it says "more than", a greater than operator must be used, not an equals sign.

Comment: You are correct on that, and that it WOULD provide the proper answer in this case... but instead of just answering the ONE question, I was trying to clarify taking it to a broader context to actually GET the MAX() value.  What if there were years where 3, 4 or 5 movies were done.  You would have 3 answers returned, and they only care about the year where 5 movies existed.  Hence the movies demo uses having = ( select max() from...) applied to it.

Comment: @DRapp, I suppose it's just a poorly worded question.  I was always taught to read a question fully before responding, so "Which were the busiest years for 'John Travolta', show the year and the number of movies he made each year for any year in which he made more than 2 movies" is not the same as "Which were the busiest years for 'John Travolta'".  To me that is like asking "At what age did you first go to school, show the year with regards to high school" and answering 5 because that's the start of kindergarten.